# How to stretch background rgba with CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is my home page: https://goprune.com

I'm trying to stretch vertically the background box behind the text "branch out of the 9-5" to contain the whole text.

This is the CSS I have to generate that background box:

```
.page-id-5 .col-md-8{
    background: rgb(204, 204, 204); /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.3);
}
```

I've tried "background-size", but it doesn't do anything.

Any way I can stretch the background box while keeping the element size the same?

Comment: All else being equal, the background colour will completely and uniformly fill the entire element. If it doesn't cover the area you want, then it is the *element* that doesn't cover that area.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/fQ10bCB

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use padding, as in

```
.page-id-5 .col-md-8{
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.3);
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Or just use `height`.

```
.page-id-5 .col-md-8{
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.3);
    height: 500px;
}
```